# automatically update label every week

Tags: ios, swift

So I was wondering, how could I update a specific label once every week. I have a recipe app and want to present the user with new recipe once a week, i would get the recipe name from an Array

```
    var recipeArray = ["Pasta, Fish, Meatballs"]

    var weekNumber = 0

    func weeklyRecipe () {
        //trigger once a week
        if weekNumber <= (recipeArray.count - 1) {
            weekNumber += 1
        } else {
            weekNumber = 0
        }
        label.text = recipeArray[weekNumber]
    }
```

I have no idea how to work with calendar, and will appreciate any help on the topic.

Comment: You can schedule a notification for a weekday.

Comment: Have a look at the Calendar API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update recipe on any particular day. Suppose you want to update on Sunday. Then

```
let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
if weekday == 1 {
    // Code for updation
}
```